# Can't restore HDD using multiple programs

Tags: hard-drive-recovery, testdisk

Please refer to [my original question](https://superuser.com/questions/514508/recovering-a-hdd) about this issue. I tried GetDataBack and it doesn't seem to scan or do anything. I chose the default settings from the first screen and then on step 1 I chose my HDD that's damaged.

In step 2, nothing happens. It doesn't scan or do anythong, and on step 3 it doesn't display any of my files.

[image]

[image]

I have also tried TestDisk and what happens in TestDisk is that when I try to fix and rebuild the MFT, it says this:

> MFT and MFT mirror are bad. Failed to repair them.

Here is the status of that HDD under Testdrive:

[image]

I also tried this app and got no results when I tried to recover the files. I keep getting this error:

[image]

Last but not least, I tried Recuva and that simply says it's unable to read the MFT.

Any suggestions? I have tried various apps already and none of them seems to work.

Comment: If three programs confirm it is broken, it is broken; last resort is using some forensics software, like WinHEX for instance, although those are paid software. Consider making back-ups instead.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have messed up a partition table, there is no guarantee that you will get anything back.

The tools you have tried do check the simple aspects, but along the way it is more than likely that MFT/Partition data has been overwritten.

The next step we would use is a tool like [EnCase](http://www.guidancesoftware.com/encase-forensic.htm) which pulls raw data from even damaged drives and then lets you analyse it for strings, patterns etc, but it is expensive commercial software.

Tom is right - you're beating a dead horse at this stage. Backups are **essential**.

Comment: How is it possible to overwrite the partition? ocne i notice it was messed up i never tried to reformat it

Comment: Unless you use write-blockers, any tool you use may write information to the disk.

Comment: Damm so it seems i am out of luck i guess